# Jest unable to mock an api call successfully

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs

Unable to mock api call successfuly in Jest test

networkHelper,js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getOptions = (url, userKeys) => axios.get(`${url}value=${userKeys}`)
    .then((res) => res);
```

Test in jest is as follows:

```
options.test.js

const mockData = [
    { label: 'SEABROOK, 3028, VIC' },
    { label: 'SEABIRD, 6042, WA' },
];

jest.mock('axios');

describe('test api', ()=> {
    it('should resolve api call', async () => {
        axios.get.mockResolvedValue({data: mockData});

        const fetchOptions =getOptions('http://localhost:8080/options, 'seab');
        expect(fetchOptions.data).toEqual(mockData);
    }
})
```

If i run the above test, I get

```
Promise.pending()
```

and if i run as

```
await getOptions('http://localhost:8080/options, 'seab');
```

then I am getting network error.

I am unsure why this is happening , can someone please point out, what I am missing here. I dont want to make a network call, but with await its making a network call

Answer (score 0):

## Update

According to [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules):

> Jest ships with experimental support for ECMAScript Modules (ESM).

> The implementation may have bugs and lack features.

It's probably possible to use ESM in your tests by following the instructions in the docs linked above.

Or, you could use CommonJS as follows:

```js
// options.js

const axios = require('axios');

module.exports.getOptions = (url, userKeys) => axios.get(`${url}value=${userKeys}`)
  .then((res) => res);
```

```js
// options.test.js

const axios = require('axios');
const { getOptions } = require('./options');

const mockData = [
  { label: 'SEABROOK, 3028, VIC' },
  { label: 'SEABIRD, 6042, WA' },
];

jest.mock('axios');

describe('test api', () => {
  it('should resolve api call', async () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: mockData });

    const fetchOptions = await getOptions('http://localhost:8080/options', 'seab');
    expect(fetchOptions.data).toEqual(mockData);
  });
});
```

I have confirmed on my machine that this test passes as expected.

---

## Previous Answer

Does it work if you add the missing close parenthesis?

```
it('should resolve api call', async () => {
  ...
}); // Missing close parenthesis here
```

Comment: Yes Alan, i think I missed it here in stack question, but its there in my code, else I would have got sysntax error  :)

Comment: Any help or pointers will be appreciiated

Comment: @sk215 I've updated the answer. Please let me know if that works for you.